# Spyder: python and ipython intepreters not starting

Tags: python, spyder

I am a frequent user of spyder for developping in python and since a few days, when I execute spyder, no python or ipython interpreters can be started available within the spyder environnement.

The initial interpreter when I execute spyder is grayed out (like it is stopped), and when I click on the "play" button to start the interpreter, it stops right away and stays grayed out.

When I look at the execution options (F6) it is still possible to use an external terminal to run the scripts but I can't execute the scripts in a dedicated python interpreter neither can I execute it in the current python/ipython interpreter.

Does anyone have an idea about how I can resolve this?

I have updated matplotlib to 1.5 and some other libraries, prior to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, also after updating matplotlib (and a number of other packages). I solved the problem by updating Spyder:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade spyder
```

Comment: That's also what I did in the end. Thanks Michael.